# Communication from C++ to Arduino Programming language on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, arduino, serial-port

I have been scouring the internet for some time now trying to figure out how to send data from C++ (which will read an input .txt file) to an Arduino. Because there does not seem to be a native way in Arduino to read files directly, I chose to use C++ to read the file and then send it over to the Arduino. The primary method of doing this seems to be communicating via Serial. So my question is this:

> How do you communicate to Serial in C++ (using an OS X device) and subsequently read it in Arduino? Further, are there other, simpler methods of transferring data to Arduino via C++ or natively in Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html) or [Qt Serial Port](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html).
Both are portable versions for serial-communication with C++.

There is no other option, which could be simpler than serial communication.